# What does "when you’re talking to the cool kids around the water cooler" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The DOM is what you call bits of rendered HTML when you’re talking to the cool kids around the water cooler.

What is the meaning of the when statement ("when you’re talking to the cool kids around the water cooler") in this sentence?

Answer (score 8):

*Watercooler chat* is the informal chatter that occurs in offices. It's where gossip is traded, sporting teams are discussed, and weekend and after-work plans are made.

*Cool kids* (in this context) would refer to the people in your workplace who are particularly smart or funny; the people you would like to impress.

To extrapolate: *the cool kids around the water cooler* are the people you want to impress in a social or informal way at your workplace.

To extrapolate further: *when you’re talking to the cool kids around the water cooler* you would want to make sure you're using the correct terminology, in order to be perceived by the said "cool kids" as clever.